# Copy Pasting Results from Teradata SQL Assistant to Excel

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

[image: When I try to copy paste data into Excel from Teradata this is what it looks like]

Previously when I had copy pasted the results directly from Teradata onto Excel it would be fine and separate itself into the respective cells but now it's doing this? (Looks like CSV file). Anyone know how to change it back?

Comment: By default, SQL Assistant uses commas between columns.  It looks like Excel is not treating the comma as a delimiter. That's a Windows setting - how you change that depends on your Windows version.

Comment: Hey Andrew! So I just checked my Windows Setting. Under List Separator, the comma is indeed listed. So I'm a bit confused as to why this problem persists. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Restarted computer and this is working fine now. Strange

Comment: "Strange" or simply "Windows" :-)